# how to loop add statement in array lists

Tags: java, arraylist

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {

      ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();

      names.add(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter type of pie"));

   }
```

How would I loop this statement? I've tried `dowhile (!names.equalsIgnoreCase("q"));` but it can't find it.

```
      names.add(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter type of pie"));
```

Comment: What do you mean it can't find it?

Comment: Compile error says can't find symbol "names"

Comment: Does it work before you add the for loop?

I.e does the code you posted above compile?

Comment: `names` is a `List`, obviously it cannot equal "q"; regardless of case. What exactly are you trying to do??

Comment: I'm trying to repeat the input dialog until the user enters q

Comment: So get the input, then check if it's `q`. You can stop looping then.

Comment: What you want your condition inside your loop statement to be is to check if the input is "q". Then stop looping. It should have nothing to do with your `names` array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This work fine.

```
     String str = null;
     List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
     do
     {
      str = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter type of pie");
   if(!str.equalsIgnoreCase("q"))
      names.add(str);
     }while(!str.equalsIgnoreCase("q"));
```

Comment: So adding "q" to the list is okay?

Comment: You can just make it into a `while` loop and avoid adding `q` to the `List` that way - this is rather ugly.

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    List<String> names = new ArrayList();
    String input = "";
    while (!input.equalsIgnoreCase("q")) {
        input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter type of pie");
        if (!input.equalsIgnoreCase("q")) {
            names.add(input);
        }
    }

    System.out.println(names);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your loop, you should iterate through the names list and call equalsIgnoreCase("q") on each element, adding another input dialog each iteration.

consider:

```
while (names.isEmpty() || !names.get(names.size() - 1).equalsIgnoreCase("q"))
{
    names.add(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter type of pie"));
}
```

And if you'd like to disregard the name of the pie "q":

```
while (names.isEmpty() || !names.get(names.size() - 1).equalsIgnoreCase("q"))
{
    names.add(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter type of pie"));
}
// populates the ArrayList names with the JOptionPane user input
if (!names.isEmpty())
{
    names.remove(names.size() - 1);
    // remove the last name inputted by the user
    // since the only way to terminate the loop is by entering "q",
    // you are removing the name of "q" from the list.
}
```

EDIT:
this is a better implementation since it only adds the names which aren't "q":

```
String userInput = new String();
while (!userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("q"))
{
    userInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter type of pie");
    if (!userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("q"))
    {
        names.add(userInput);
    }
}
```